# Do enum types undergo default argument promotion?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Can the type of the last argument before `...` in a variadic function be an enum type?

Do `enum` types undergo default argument promotion?

There are some contexts where types that undergo default argument promotion cannot be used safely, with vararg handling (`va_start`, `va_arg`) being a notable example. The compilers I use seem to treat `enum` types as an `int`, which is safe to use in these contexts. Is this always the case? Can I safely use an enum type as the last argument before `...` in variadic functions?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. You should be able to use any type in that place.  That parameter must have a type in parameter list and no conversions will be made. Only the arguments for the `...` part are promoted.

Comment: @Gerhardh The very last argument before the `...` must not undergo default argument promotion. This is because `va_start` may be implemented as a macro that just takes the last non-variadic argument and shifts its address by the size of its type. If the type gets promoted then this size will not be accurate. In practice, `va_start` is not a dumb macro but a smart built-in with all of GCC, Clang, and MSVC, or at least using a promoted type works fine with all three of these compilers. But Clang still issues a warning that we're invoking undefined behaviour by doing this.

Comment: @Gerhardh Here's the small program that I used to test that doing this does not break with these compilers. It also demonstrates the warning issued by Clang. https://godbolt.org/z/rvaxanj77

Comment: So, it is about promotion when passing to `va_start`, not while passing to your function. OK. I missed that.

Comment: From what I remember, an `enum` type in **C** always has an underlying type of `int`, so default promotion won't happen. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum): *Each enumeration-constant that appears in the body of an enumeration specifier becomes an integer constant with type int in the enclosing scope and can be used whenever integer constants are required (e.g. as a case label or as a non-VLA array size).*

Comment: @AdrianMole it has an underlying integer type but it does not have to be `int`. It could alcs be 8 bits.

Comment: @Gerhardh OK - I read more thoroughly and you're right: it's implementation-defined what the underlying type is.

Comment: @AdrianMole As you can see from the debate here, there are some subtleties, which is why I asked the question. My interpretation of that sentence is that the enum constant is an `int`, but that does not mean that the enum type is also an `int`. I.e., with `enum Foo { A = 1 };`, `A` is equivalent to `1`, which is an `int`. But what is `sizeof(enum Foo)`? My understanding was that it is not guaranteed to be `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @AdrianMole the first comment from SomeProgrammerDude it taken from "6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers" of C standard.

Comment: In fact, IIRC, there was some strange compiler (CodeWarrior?) that I used in the last millennium that had an "enum always int" option/flag available.

Comment: @Aconcagua See the godbolt link in the comments above, and the Clang warning there. See also [the note on undefined behaviour for `va_start`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_start)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “All enumeration constants are compatible with either char, a "signed integer type", or an "unsigned integer type"”: C 2018 6.4.4.3 2 says “An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type `int`.” The enumeration type, not its constants, “shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type,” per 6.7.2.2 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, default argument promotion can happen depending on the underlying type chosen for an `enum`.

From section 6.7.2.2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) regarding enumeration specifiers:

> **Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer
> type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
> implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
> values of all the members of the enumeration.** The enumerated type is
> incomplete until immediately after the `}` that terminates the list of
> enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter

So an implementation may choose to use a type smaller than `int` as the underlying type, and if so then it is subject to default argument promotions.  GCC in particular will do this if you specify the `-fshort-enums` flag.

And if that's the case, you can't use that `enum` as the last named argument in a variadic function.  From section 7.16.1.4p4 regarding `va_start`:

> The parameter `parmN` is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in
> the variable parameter list in the function definition (the one just
> before the , `...`). **If the parameter `parmN` is declared with the
> `register` storage class, with a function or array type, *or with a type
> that is not compatible with the type that results after application of
> the default argument promotions*, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Thanks, this answers my main question. Two more followup questions: 1. What does it mean that "type A is _not compatible_ with type B" and how does _not compatible_ differ from _not the same_ in this context? This refers to the last quote in your answer. 2. Do you happen to know of any cases when using such a type for the last named argument actually causes problems? There are no problems with any of the compilers available [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rvaxanj77) on any platforms where Godbolt can execute code. Clang is the only compiler that even ...

Comment: ... emits warnings about this. GCC and MSVC do not. I understand that this is undefined behaviour in the barebones standard, but is there any extension to that standard where it becomes defined? To clarify what I mean by extension, I am thinking of a situation analogous to `1.0 / 0.0` being undefined behaviour in the barebones standard. It is however defined on all IEEE-754 compliant platforms, which is all I need to care about.

Comment: In other words: I am looking for information that will help me decide whether I actually need to worry about this instance of undefined behaviour. I am wondering if there is any standard (perhaps an extension to the C standard, comparable to the floating point extensions) within which it becomes defined.

Comment: Technically, there is another problem here. The enumeration type can be compatible with any signed or unsigned integer type, per C 6.7.2.2 4. The enumeration constants have type `int`. So, if the C implementation makes the enumeration type compatible with `unsigned long`, but you pass the enumeration constant `foo` as the argument, then calling `va_arg(ap, enum bar)` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see what you mean, but the C implementation would need to be pretty insane to make `enum` types wider than `int`. (I think GCC defaults to using `unsigned int` unless the enumeration contains negative values, or if `-fshort-enums` is specified or if that is the default for a particular ABI.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil This would seem to apply to an `enum` constant being one of the variadic arguments, not the last named argument.  So yes it could be a problem, but not in this particular case.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was thinking of passing an `enum` in the `...`, not before it.